# Intel Windows install to amd

Tags: windows-10, computer-building, intel-pentium, amd-cpu

Is it possible to take a Windows installation on a HDD that was installed with an Intel cpu, and transfer the HDD to an AMD build?

Aka I have an Intel pc, then I take the HDD with win10 on it and connect it to an AMD pc. Would it work?

Or are my hopes too high?

Comment: Of course it is.  AMD CPUs are x86 CPUs but you can't just transfer a Windows installation like you describe there is more to the process but that process is well documented

Comment: It may not works. Because the whole hardware is changed including motherboard. And windows stores hardware settings in registry.

Comment: You should sysprep it with the /generalize switch before migrating. This should allow Windows to rebuild the drivers needed for the new machine and then you finish installing the rest of the drivers from within Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible.  The big problem is drivers.  If you just swap the hard drive to the new machine, it will be expecting a different motherboard, different CPU, different video card, etc, for dozens of different devices.  As Appleoddity suggested, you can run Microsoft System Preparation before moving the HD.  In my experience, it's always cleaner to start with a fresh installation.
Some useful links : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation

https://www.howtogeek.com/239815/why-cant-you-move-a-windows-installation-to-another-computer/

Comment: Thanks, I asked because I'm considering switching from Intel to an AMD cpu, and in turn the motherboard and wasn't sure if I would have to reinstall windows